# Menu/Toolbar color in WPF app

Tags: wpf, menu, toolbar

So I have a simple WPF app with a menu and a toolbar/toolbartray inside a Grid. By default, the colors don't match (the menu is grey and the toolbar is blue - see image)

[image]

I have tried specifically setting the background color but there are then other issues (toolbar overflow button colors and sub menu colors.)

Strikes me that by default, the colors should match and also match the system theme. Is there a magic setting? Surely I can't need to specifically style everything?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Get default `ControlTemplates` of that controls.

   - [Menu](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296(v=vs.110).aspx)
   - [ToolBar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970772(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Add new `ResourceDictionary` to your project and insert that templates
3. Change background properties in root `Borders` of templates.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is that really what I must do, just to get a consistent Menu/Toolbar style? I'm not looking to style anything beyond 'system default' and 'consistent'. Seems bizarre to me!

Comment: if you want to use system default - don't change menu system colors. If you want to change something - edit a default template if its not changing like you want

Comment: ...but then the menu and toolbar are different colors - which can't be right?

Comment: i don't know why ms designers sets different sys colors. Maybe there is some point we didn't consider about.